# Prototype 1.7.1 observe in IE8 (and ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototype, handler

Here ruby code:

```
template.javascript_include_once "phonejs"
...
template.javascript_tag "document.on('dom:loaded', function() { $('#{options[:id]}').observe('click', respondToClick, false);  });"
```

respondToClick in "phonejs" file, but in IE8 'respondToClick' - missing operand

It's work fine in any other brousers (firefox, opera, chrome).
I think IE can't find function, but I can't resolve this problem.

Help please :)
And sorry for my english.

Comment: change respondToClick on function(){ blablabla...} works in IE too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change respondToClick on function(){ respondToClick();}